# RiotJS use property as class name

Tags: riot.js

Let's consider following template:

```
<ul class="clearfix">
  <li each={ timeslot, i in events } 
    class={ ??? } 
    data={ timeslot }
    style="width: { timeslot.len*100 }px;">    
       <div>{ timeslot.start.format() }</div>
       <div>{ timeslot.title }</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have a `state` property in my `timeslot` object, that has the exact same set of values I would like to use as class names. Thus it would be straightforward to use `class={ timeslot.state }`. But *class* is evaluated differently. 
Is there any way to avoid expressions in this case and use the property as it is as class name?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a `{}` expression, it can be evaluated in a number of ways. If you are setting as an object, IE: `class={foo: true, bar: false }` it is treated like a list of class names to add based on whether the value of each key is true-ish.

BUT... if you do `class="{ timeslot.classname }"` - it will instead be treated like a string and the output will be the `class="whatever"` you are looking for... as long as `timeslot.classname` is a string.

Comment: As you see in my question, this was the first I have tried - as this was straightforward. And it did not work, I got a riot compiler error. Now that you insisted on it, I have put the original expression back... and it works. I don't get it... really... Thanks anyway.

Comment: I think the quotes are an important hint.  I think Riot treats {} expressions in strings differently than when not.

Comment: Right. I have overseen this at first.

Answer (score 0):

In > 3.4.0 you can create an object, which will then do what you want:
`timeslot.state={SomeClass:true}`

See http://riotjs.com/guide/#expressions and scroll to `Class object expressions`

Comment: I know this, and this is not what I want. I want the class attribute value to be the value of a property of timeslot object. I have three possible string values and I would like to use them as they are. With expressions I need to check each one by one.
`class={ free: timeslot.state == "free", occupied: timeslot.state == "occupied", closed: timeslot.state == "closed" }`

Comment: No, this is different: please check the section I referenced.

Comment: I have checked. Seems not much of a difference. I need two steps to use it:
`timeslot.className = {};
timeslot.className[timeslot.state] = true;`
Then this works `<... class={ timeslot.className }>`... well not too nice...